# Cloud Datastore batch insert entities while recognising if the same key already exist?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to create a Cloud Dataflow 2.x (aka Apache Beam) `PTransform` to filter out elements of a `PCollection` that were already "seen" previously.

The basic idea is that the PTransform gets a Function to calculate a *natural id* (a "primary key") for each of the PCollection's elements. Each of these ids will be used to create a Cloud Datastore Key and stored in a dummy Entity Kind ("table"); if the insertion fails due to a duplicate key error, then I know that I already have seen the corresponding *natural id* and therefore the same PCollection element.

I assume the best way to implements this is by using Bundles in the DoFn and issue batch requests to Datastore in my @FinishBundle method.

I understand that I cannot use transactional commits in this case because if just one Insert mutation fails due to its key already existing, it will make the whole transaction fail, and the documentation says that's impossible to understand which of the Keys is the already existing one.

If I use non-transactional Inserts, am I guaranteed that concurrent inserts of the same Key will have at least one of them fail?

Otherwise, which other options do I have? I'd rather not use transactions with just one mutation, but batch multiple mutations together.

I'm using the `datastore-v1-proto-client` / `datastore-v1-protos` API (aka the plain Datastore v1 REST API), not the new `google-cloud-datastore` API.

Comment: Perhaps i misunderstand, but wouldn't concurrent inserts of the same Key just overwrite each other? Although a very high amount would cause a contention error for some of them. But you could just try-catch-ignore those, since that is effectively what an overwrite would do anyway.